# set binding context to a property

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I want to be able to create a binding context by binding to a property, in a similar way how the `with` binding works:

```
<div data-bind="with: myData">
         <button data-bind="text: myHeader"></button>
</div>
```

But I don't want to use `with` because it recreates the HTML elements (the `button` in my example) each time `myData` changes, see  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html:

> If the expression you supply involves any observable values, the
>   expression will be re-evaluated whenever any of those observables
>   change. Then, descendant elements will be cleared out, and a new copy
>   of the markup will be added to your document and bound in the context
>   of the new evaluation result.

So I need something similar to `with` binding, let's say a `context` binding:

```
<div data-bind="context: myData">
         <button data-bind="text: myHeader"></button>
</div>
```

`<button>` is now bound to the `myData` context, so I don't have to write:

```
<div>
         <button data-bind="text: myData().myHeader"></button>
</div>
```

This is also described in 
http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/03/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha-1ifwith.html

> The with binding is very handy for binding against nested
>   objects/models and helps to keep your data-bind attributes from
>   becoming too verbose. It is important, however, to understand that the
>   with binding will re-render the entire section whenever its bound
>   value changes.

Does something like this exists in KO?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that quote from the docs means what you think it does.

If there are observables in the object that you use in the `with` binding, and those observables change, then the body of the element that has the the `with` binding **will not be re-rendered unconditionally**.

Try it. Run this snippet and type into the input element while the counter increments:

```js
var vm = {
  sample: {
    counter: ko.observable(0)
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);

setInterval(function () {
  vm.sample.counter( vm.sample.counter() + 1);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: sample">
  <input type="text" value="type here">
  <div>Counter: <span data-bind="text: counter"></span><div>
</div>
```

What the documentation means: If the `with` binding points to an observable, and *that* observable changes, then the body of the element will be re-rendered.

*"If the expression you supply involves any observable values,"* refers to the expression you give to the `with` binding. In your case that expression is a single value, `myData`. Whether there are any observables *inside of* `myData` is completely irrelevant.